# Mysql parameters that affect Table Creation Duration

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am running a query from mysql terminal:

```
CREATE TABLE test(ID int, col1 id, col2 ID, PRIMARY KEY (ID) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Using the SHOW PROFILE command I get an average of :

creating table duration = 0.008000 which equals to about 8ms.

Any suggestions what parameters to look in mysql configuration to improve table creation time? 
In other words what parameters can affect the table creation time.

I am using a Intel Xeon 3.80GHz with 4Gb ram.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some variables which might affect the `CREATE TABLE`-performance:

- hardware i/o
- file system
- mysql version
- ram
- database engine type (innodb / myisam / ...)
- table design (keys, fields, ...)
- connection to the database
- a few other database server configurations

All in all I'd say 8ms are ok, but thats said without knowing more details.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is not much on the software side you can configure for table creation specifically.  Hardware may help, start by adding more RAM if you can.  However, there was a previous [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924083/tuning-mysql-for-speedy-column-index-creation-during-development) question that may lend some assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the parameters will depend on the database engine you are using. Assuming its InnoDB (the default), take a look at `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and `innodb_additional_mem_pool_size`

That being said, I doubt you will be able to see that much improvement off of 8 ms.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a problem for you that a table creation requires 8 milliseconds then there is quite likely something wrong with your database design (that would be the case if you want to create a thousand tables per second).

If you are using them just temporary, use tables that are stored in memory:

```
CREATE TABLE test(ID int, col1 id, col2 ID, 
PRIMARY KEY (ID))
ENGINE=MEMORY;
```

Creation will be faster, however if your server crashes then the data in those tables is lost.